# Restrict log messages sent to appinsight from my App Service

Tags: .net, logging, azure-web-app-service

My App Service is logging to appinsights using a TelemetryClient. This works fine and I get everything logged as expected. The problem I have is that it is now logging too much and my costs for appinsights is going way too high. I need to reduce the logging by just capturing warnings and errors but be able to log debug and trace message if there is a problem. I have done this with my Azure Function’s by adding filters to the logging section of the Function’s host.json file. Is there a similar way to do this with an App Service project so I can change the log level filtering via the portal rather than having to recompile and deploy a new release?

The host.json for my Azure Function looks like this. I am after something similar for my App Service website:

```
"logging": {
    "fileLoggingMode": "always",
    "logLevel": {
        "Function": "Warning",
        "Default": "Warning",
        "System": "Information",
        "Microsoft": "Warning",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal": "Information",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication": "Information"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Azure monitor provides a simple way to configure LogLevel for ASP.NET Core. The filtering can be done either in configuration (typically by using an `appsettings.json` file) or in code.

The below sample is provided by the official doc: [Create filter rules in configuration with appsettings.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/ilogger#create-filter-rules-in-configuration-with-appsettingsjson).

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "ApplicationInsights": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Warning",
        "Microsoft": "Error"
      }
    },
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

**Update:** For asp .net I found the [ApplicationInsights.config](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/configuration-with-applicationinsights-config) could specify the Telemetry Modules level. The below is the sample about [EventSource events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-trace-logs#use-eventsource-events).

```
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.EventSourceListener.EventSourceTelemetryModule, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.EventSourceListener">
      <Sources>
        <Add Name="MyCompany" Level="Verbose" />
      </Sources>
    </Add>
```

Comment: Unfortunately my project doesn't use .net core, it is stuck on .net framework 4.7.1 Also your link doesn't work for me.

Comment: @Ian Munro, I have updated the link  and the answer. Check if this what you want

Comment: I have got round my problem by adding an environment variable and filtering the logging manually based on this setting. The EventSource event section is interesting but my hacky fix has got me out of having to fiddle with the code too much. Thanks for your input.